# Android: SugarORM and multidex

Tags: android, android-multidex, sugarorm

I'm working with Android project that uses SugarORM. Now the method limit has increased so much that I have to activate multidex support. But now I have a problem with SugarORM, it creates only the tables that are in classes.dex file. It seems to ignore classes2.dex completely. Is that really a bug in Sugar and is there some good way to bypass the problem?

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug on Sugar ORM with Multidex. The reflection api doesn't find your model classes when they are out of primary dex file, so It doesn't allow the framework to generate your tables correctly. Hope that it helps.