# SugarORM + Multidex

Tags: android, android-multidex, sugarorm

I downloaded the SugarORM source to use it as a library module (so I could override the aplication's  "attachBaseContext" method.

I have already seen the question [SugarORM and multidex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051716/android-sugarorm-and-multidex), Problem is that I can't figure out how to reference the MultiDex library into my new SugarORM library module.
Can someone help me figuring this out?

[Error page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6bBZ.png)

Answer (score 7):

Create a class java file

```
public class MultiDex extends SugarApp {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        android.support.multidex.MultiDex.install(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SugarContext.init(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        SugarContext.terminate();
        super.onTerminate();
    }
}
```

In Manifest, call the java class file.

```
<application
   .......
    android:name=".MultiDex"

   ......>
```

Check the version of sugar library 
  
 and make sure you complie the latest version of sugar library . Using version like 1.3 will throw some errors with multidex.

add this in your gradle

```
 compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
```

Answer (score -1):

If possible, extend the MultiDexApplication yourself:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication
```

Also, ensure you have followed [all steps](http://blog.osom.info/2014/10/multi-dex-to-rescue-from-infamous-65536.html) required to configure MultiDex.

Particularly build.gradle:

```
android {
   defaultConfig {
      ...
      multiDexEnabled = true
}
```

And AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    .. >
 ..
</application>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jake. I had not thought about extending MultiDexAplication.
It turned out I decided to compile using API 23, which natively supports multidex (because of ART Runtine).